# Error: in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using Python 3.6.3.  I am trying to run my first ML code, for the first time ever.  Here is the code.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.linear_model

#load the data
oecd_bli = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/rschuell/Desktop/oecd_bli.csv",thousands=',')
gdp_per_capita = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/rschuell/Desktop/gdp_per_capita.csv",thousands=',',delimiter='\t',encoding='latin1',na_values='n/a')

#prepare the data
def prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita):
    #get the pandas dataframe of GDP per capita and Life satisfaction
    oecd_bli = oecd_bli[oecd_bli["INEQUALITY"]=="TOT"]
    oecd_bli = oecd_bli.pivot(index="Country", columns="Indicator", values="Value")
    gdp_per_capita.rename(columns={"2015": "GDP per capita"}, inplace=True)
    gdp_per_capita.set_index("Country", inplace=True)
    full_country_stats = pd.merge(left=oecd_bli, right=gdp_per_capita, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    return full_country_stats[["GDP per capita", 'Life satisfaction']]
    
country_stats = prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita) 
#regularization remove_indices = [0, 1, 6, 8, 33, 34, 35]
country_stats.to_csv('country_stats.csv',encoding='utf-8')
X = np.c_[country_stats["GDP per capita"]]
Y = np.c_[country_stats["Life satisfaction"]]

#Visualize the data
country_stats.plot(kind='scatter',x='GDP per capita',y='Life satisfaction')

#Select a linear model
lin_reg_model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()

#Train the model
lin_reg_model.fit(X, Y)

#plot Regression model
t0, t1 = lin_reg_model.intercept_[0], lin_reg_model.coef_[0][0]
X = np.linspace(0, 110000, 1000)
plt.plot(X, t0 + t1 * X, "k")
plt.show()

#Make a prediction for Cyprus
X_new=[[22587]]
print(lin_reg_model.predict(X_new))


import sys
print (sys.version)
```

I got it from the link below.

http://www.cnblogs.com/yaoz/p/6858417.html

When I run the code, I get an error here:

```
country_stats = prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita) 
#regularization remove_indices = [0, 1, 6, 8, 33, 34, 35]
country_stats.to_csv('country_stats.csv',encoding='utf-8')
X = np.c_[country_stats["GDP per capita"]]
Y = np.c_[country_stats["Life satisfaction"]]
```

Error message reads:

```
 File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Country'
```

I think the variables are read in, and assigned correctly.

[image]

I don't know what the issue is. How can I get this to run?

Comment: Are you sure that you have  column for 2015 year in variable gdb_per_capita in the function?

Comment: Bo, the years go from 1960-2011.  I downloaded both files from here:  https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/tree/master/datasets/lifesat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program works perfectly for me and shows:

[image]
[[6.28653637]]

with Jypyther on the following versions:
The version of the notebook server is: 5.2.2
3.6.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov  4 2017, 10:10:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)]

only think which I changed the 8th line:

```
oecd_bli = pd.read_csv("oecd_bli.csv",thousands=',')
```

to:

```
oecd_bli = pd.read_csv("oecd_bli_2015.csv",thousands=',')
```

and remember to correctly download datasets from https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/tree/master/datasets/lifesat because when I first time downloaded and there was not csv format files. Please double check them again in viewer are they really csv correct files. (I select raw files and download directly from the browser.)

Comment: Yes, yes, I think it has something to do with the way my browser is handling the CSV files.  I think something is getting mangled.  I still can't get it working, but I think that's the issue.  That chart is exactly what I expected to see!  Thanks for trying to help!!